# What is the Biblical basis for the personhood of the Holy Spirit? Is it a new revelation?

Tags: biblical-basis, pneumatology, persons-of-the-trinity, pentecostalism

I worship in a Pentecostal Church, where the Holy Spirit is endorsed. Whenever I hear gospels about the Holy Spirit I always hear the following that the Spirit is a Person.

Is there biblical excerpts or theological backgrounds to indicate that the Holy Spirit is a person or was it revealed by personal revelation of Prophets in the 20th/21th Century, which is possible as the Holy Spirit reveals to men of God but also children of GOD?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! I've marked this as a duplicate of one of our older questions, though it doesn't get into the history of how the church came to understand that the Holy Spirit is a person alongside the Father and the Son. We do have other questions getting into that history too, but in short it was understood long by the early church.

Comment: Spirits in general, whether human, angelic, or demonic, are endowed with personhood. It's not clear why the divine spirit would constitute an exception to the general rule.

Comment: What we have received is not the *spirit of the world*, but the Spirit which is from God, so that we may understand what God has freely given us. So the spirit of the world is a 'person' too?